# Android Bluetooth RFCOMM directly to Raspberry Pi without pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, rfcomm, pybluez

I need to make an application that communicates through an `RFCOMM socket` to a **Raspberry Pi**, without pairing.
On the Android side, I have the MAC address of the RPi and I'm trying to connect to the server using this code:

```
BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
BluetoothSocket mmSocket = null;

    try {
        mmSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID);
        mmSocket.connect();
        Log.d(TAG, "mmSocket returned");
    }
    ...
```

UUID is the same as on the server-side, and i've also tried using the createInsecureRfcommSocket method.

On the Raspberry Pi side, I used the pybluez example of an rfcomm server([here is the example](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/blob/master/examples/simple/rfcomm-server.py))

It once worked but I don't understand why it did or why it doesn't anymore, in the sense that when I tried to initiate the connection from the phone I got a pairing request on the Raspberry Pi without a pairing request on the phone, and the socket object on android had successfully connected.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, or any ideas that might help me, and is such a thing even feasible.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this unanswered question and I think I have a working solution at least for my case.

All I needed to do was to call these three commands:

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 piscan 
sudo hciconfig hci0 sspmode 1
sudo hciconfig hci0 class 0x400100
```

The first two lines make the RPi discoverable, [from this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/96100/143658), which also claims the RPi should pair automatically. That does NOT work for me. It still requires PIN confirmation on both devices, that's unfortunate for a headless RPi.

The third line found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56428386/cant-connect-a-socket-to-bluetooth-paired-device) is crucial and it is what allows to connect RFCOMM sockets to unpaired RPi.
**It is possible that changing class will make other BT services stop working, not sure, I just need RFCOMM.**

After this, the following example works for me with RPI 4B and my Win10 laptop:

```
import socket
from contextlib import closing

# MAC address of RPi, can be obtained with `bluetoothctl list` on RPi.
rpi_addr =  'e4:5f:01:7d:8A:A3' 
# 1-32, some might be used already, e.g. 3 for me, in that case bind fails.
channel = 15
def server():

    print("Creating socket")
    with closing(socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 
    socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)) as s:
        print("Binding socket")
        s.bind((rpi_addr ,channel))
        print("Listening socket")
        s.listen()

        s_sock, addr = s.accept()
        with closing(s_sock):
            print ("Accepted connection from "+str(addr))

            data = s_sock.send(b"Hello from RPi")

def client():

    print("Creating socket")
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 
    socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
    print("Connecting socket")
    s.connect((rpi_addr,channel))
    print("Connected")

    data = s.recv(1024)

    print(f"Received {data}")
```